# Unable to auto detect APP_BUNDLE_PATH for Calabash + Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, calabash-ios

I have integrated iOS project with Jenkins. To run the automation test cases I am using the below code in shell script.

```
export DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=`xcode-select -print-path`/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate 


xcodebuild -alltargets clean
xcodebuild -alltargets
xcodebuild -sdk iphonesimulator \
           -project Myapp.xcodeProj \
           -scheme Myapp-cal \
           ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO \
           CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR="$WORKSPACE/build" \
           clean build
cucumber
```

The automation testing is working fine in xcode where as with Jenkins getting the below error.

> Unable to auto detect APP_BUNDLE_PATH.   Have you built your app for
>   simulator?   Searched dir:
>   /Users/test/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Myapp-fayplezntrxmdqeteknsfkkvtzla/Build/Products
>   Please build your app from Xcode   You should build the -cal target.

Help appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe all you need to do is export your `APP_BUNDLE_PATH` in your script before you call cucumber.

Something like this:

```
export APP_BUNDLE_PATH="${WORKSPACE}/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Myapp-cal.app"
cucumber
```

To see an example of this in the wild see the briar-ios-example repo. [1]

FYI/BTW `APP` and `APP_BUNDLE_PATH` are interchangeable. [2]

- [1] https://github.com/jmoody/briar-ios-example/blob/master/Briar/jenkins-calabash.sh
- [2] http://calabashapi.xamarin.com/ios/file.ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES.html

Comment: I followed the steps mentioned in the link 1  and it is working fine now. Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the contents of `/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` and compiling again solved this problem for me. I did not wanted to hardcode the `APP_BUNDLE_PATH` as I have multiple targets.

My error message was `Unable to auto detect APP_BUNDLE_PATH.`